# "Bitwise operator used" or observable in Angular template

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, rxjs, observable

I have been inspired by rxjs, so my address has become an BehaviourSubject:

```
address = new BehaviorSubject<Address>(null);
```

Until user picks address on the map, it is initialized with null. In template I need to show a property of address: `address.addressLine` or message `pick address on the map`.

So I wrote:

```
{{(address | async) ? (address | async).addressLine : 'pick address on the map'}}
```

This works fine, but IDEA thinks I am using a `bitwise or`:
[image]

What should I do? Options:

1. Ignore warning
2. Ignore warning and create an issue for IDEA
3. Change my code somehow

Comment: IDEA doesn't think you are using a bitwise operator, you *are* using a bitwise operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue in IDEA, please follow [WEB-27164](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27164) for updates

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to create local variable from that observable, and use it:

```
address$ = new BehaviorSubject<Address>(null);

<ng-container *ngIf="(address$ | async) || {} as address">
  {{ address.addressLine || 'pick address on the map' }}
</ng-container>
```

This way webstorm is not complaining. Also the way you are doing it will unnecessary subscribe twice I think (which is not good for performance).

That `(address$ | async) || {}` expression is there so we always have `address` resolved, even if its `null`. You could also use `else` feature and display the placeholder message in a new `<ng-template>` or other element.

This is working in latest angular 4.4, not sure about previous versions (the syntax have changed).